# Two.js - Zoom/Pan ONLY if not on a shape + click handle on shapes

Tags: javascript, two.js

I have recently been asked to learn about Two.js, and specificaly to modify [this example](https://codepen.io/jonobr1/pen/PobMKwb). I have tried for few day to alter this code ..

```
var two = new Two({
  fullscreen: true,
  autostart: true
}).appendTo(document.body);

var stage = new Two.Group();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * two.width * 2 - two.width;
  var y = Math.random() * two.height * 2 - two.height;
  var size = 50;
  var shape = new Two.Rectangle(x, y, size, size);
  shape.rotation = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  shape.noStroke().fill = '#ccc';
  stage.add(shape);
  
}

shape.fill = 'red';
shape.position.set(two.width / 2, two.height / 2);


two.add(stage);
addZUI();

function addZUI() {

    var domElement = two.renderer.domElement;
    var zui = new Two.ZUI(stage);
    var mouse = new Two.Vector();
    var touches = {};
    var distance = 0;
    var dragging = false;

    zui.addLimits(0.06, 8);

    domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown, false);
    domElement.addEventListener('mousewheel', mousewheel, false);
    domElement.addEventListener('wheel', mousewheel, false);

    domElement.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart, false);
    domElement.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove, false);
    domElement.addEventListener('touchend', touchend, false);
    domElement.addEventListener('touchcancel', touchend, false);

    function mousedown(e) {
      mouse.x = e.clientX;
      mouse.y = e.clientY;
      var rect = shape.getBoundingClientRect();
      dragging = mouse.x > rect.left && mouse.x < rect.right
        && mouse.y > rect.top && mouse.y < rect.bottom;
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove, false);
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);
    }

    function mousemove(e) {
      var dx = e.clientX - mouse.x;
      var dy = e.clientY - mouse.y;
      if (dragging) {
        shape.position.x += dx / zui.scale;
        shape.position.y += dy / zui.scale;
      } else {
        zui.translateSurface(dx, dy);
      }
      mouse.set(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    function mouseup(e) {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove, false);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);
    }

    function mousewheel(e) {
      var dy = (e.wheelDeltaY || - e.deltaY) / 1000;
      zui.zoomBy(dy, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    function touchstart(e) {
      switch (e.touches.length) {
        case 2:
          pinchstart(e);
          break;
        case 1:
          panstart(e)
          break;
      }
    }

    function touchmove(e) {
      switch (e.touches.length) {
        case 2:
          pinchmove(e);
          break;
        case 1:
          panmove(e)
          break;
      }
    }

    function touchend(e) {
      touches = {};
      var touch = e.touches[ 0 ];
      if (touch) {  // Pass through for panning after pinching
        mouse.x = touch.clientX;
        mouse.y = touch.clientY;
      }
    }

    function panstart(e) {
      var touch = e.touches[ 0 ];
      mouse.x = touch.clientX;
      mouse.y = touch.clientY;
    }

    function panmove(e) {
      var touch = e.touches[ 0 ];
      var dx = touch.clientX - mouse.x;
      var dy = touch.clientY - mouse.y;
      zui.translateSurface(dx, dy);
      mouse.set(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
    }

    function pinchstart(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < e.touches.length; i++) {
        var touch = e.touches[ i ];
        touches[ touch.identifier ] = touch;
      }
      var a = touches[ 0 ];
      var b = touches[ 1 ];
      var dx = b.clientX - a.clientX;
      var dy = b.clientY - a.clientY;
      distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      mouse.x = dx / 2 + a.clientX;
      mouse.y = dy / 2 + a.clientY;
    }

    function pinchmove(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < e.touches.length; i++) {
        var touch = e.touches[ i ];
        touches[ touch.identifier ] = touch;
      }
      var a = touches[ 0 ];
      var b = touches[ 1 ];
      var dx = b.clientX - a.clientX;
      var dy = b.clientY - a.clientY;
      var d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      var delta = d - distance;
      zui.zoomBy(delta / 250, mouse.x, mouse.y);
      distance = d;
    }
  
}
```

.. in order to make it work this way :

Zoom : on wheel, no change.
Dragging : only if mousedown in space between shapes.
Shape click : execute a function.

I tried many things base on answers found here and doc, but nothing work at all, an some pieces of code could be seen as a damn blasphemy.

I don't ask for a complete working code (if someone can provide it I will study it gladly), but any explanations or hints will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Comment out all the code with `mousewheel` to disable mousewheel. This would be the event listeners and the function that handles those events.

Comment: For being able to click on each object and not handle the pan, you can add event listeners on each of the objects. Something like: `shape.renderer.elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });` after `two.add(stage);`